# How to prevent placeholder strings in a storyboard from being included in the .strings file?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm localizing my storyboards using Base and Xcode-generated .strings files. The problem is my storyboards have quite a lot of placeholder text that will be replaced programmatically at runtime. I can manually remove those rows from the .strings files before I pass them to the translators, but every time I refresh my .strings files with ibtool, those rows will be added by it again.

Is there any way to mark certain UI elements (`UILabel`, etc.) in the interface builder as placeholder that should be skipped by ibtool?

Comment: Answer would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marking some XIB/Storyboard strings as not localizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407282/marking-some-xib-storyboard-strings-as-not-localizable)