# Xcode - exclude certain strings from localization

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, localization, uistoryboard

When localizing my storyboard, I get entries in my strings file that look like:

`/* Class = "NSTextFieldCell"; title = "Text Cell"; ObjectID = "vHF-LZ-23i"; */
"vHF-LZ-23i.title" = "Text Cell";`

Is there anyway to exclude dummy text or other strings from going into the storyboard localization strings files?

Comment: No, there is no such option as I know.

Comment: Can't you just remove them from the file?

Comment: This file is generated whenever the localization strings change so that isn't a great solution

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407282/marking-some-xib-storyboard-strings-as-not-localizable for a potential workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 7):

As Jenszcz mentioned in his comment that you can solve this problem by using [BartyCrouch](https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch) open-source project, I was curios to give it a try And worked excellently :) Here are the steps I followed to get it work within 5 minutes.

1- Install [BartyCrouch](https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch). See the installation procedure from url.

2- Created a sample project, which you can access [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5skf3pvoc5whzn6/AADm_T8kY6wD3s9pcURc2lhqa?dl=0). In that project created 2 labels ("Text Included" & "Text Excluded #bc-ignore!").

3- Add RunScript (instructions on how to add a build script [here](https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch#build-script))

```
if which bartycrouch > /dev/null; then
    bartycrouch update -x
    bartycrouch lint -x
else
    echo "warning: BartyCrouch not installed, download it from https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch"
fi
```

[image]

4- After building the project the Main.strings file excluded one label.Here are the screenshots showing the storyboard file & .strings file.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[ReMafoX](https://remafox.app)**, it's a Mac app that perfectly solves your problem. It can be **easily installed and integrated** within your project, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObGIiWARjmw&list=PLvkAveYAfY4TLPtPd5jnqMwpAzY_pdxs5&index=1) for a detailed walkthrough.

To ignore specific Strings, simply add one of the customizable ignore flags from the "Interface Builder" pane in the "Comment for Localizer" field in your Storyboard/XIB files and the build-script you configured following the above linked video will exclude it on next build of your project (or press of the "Update" button in the config).

[image: Config Option, Interface Builder pane]