# Localize Storyboard but mark certain text to not be translated

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, localization, uistoryboard

I am wanting to localize my storyboard into German. Xcode does a great job of creating a main.strings file for my storyboard. However, I am using prototype cells for many of my table views. Each of those cells just uses dummy text in the `UILabel`s since I replace the text later when I load the data to populate the table view.

Prototype Cell:

[image]

Storyboard Strings file:

[image]

Strings file string that I don't want:
[image]

Is there a way to tell Xcode to ignore certain strings so that they don't even show up in the strings file? I don't want to have to pay a translator to translate dummy text.

Comment: I guess one of my options is to just not import the strings that I don't want into the translation server. iCanLocalize provides this option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marking some XIB/Storyboard strings as not localizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407282/marking-some-xib-storyboard-strings-as-not-localizable)